# How do I link two views to one template file in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to build a very basic messaging app where someone types into a text input, presses send then see's the message on the screen. And I want to do all of this on the same URL. Here is what I have right now:

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from message import models


# Create your views here.
class ViewMessages(ListView):
    model = models.Messages
    context_object_name = 'messages'


class WriteMessages(CreateView):
    fields = ('message',)
    model = models.Messages
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


# Create your models here.
class Messages(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("view")
```

**project urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from message import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^view/', views.ViewMessages.as_view(), name="view"),
    url(r'^create/', views.WriteMessages.as_view(), name="create"),
]
```

**messages_form.html**

```
{% extends "message/base.html" %}

{% block head_block %}
<title>Create Message</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

{% for message in messages %}
<h3><div class="text-center"><span class="label label-default">{{ message.message }}</span></div></h3>
{% endfor %}

<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="text-center" style="position: fixed; top: 500px;">
    <span style="margin: 10px;">{{ form }}</span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-group btn-group-lg" >
  </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**messages_list.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "message/base.html" %}

{% block head_block %}
<title>Read Messages</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="">
{% for message in messages %}
<h3><div class="text-center"><span class="label label-default">{{ message.message }}</span></div></h3>
{% endfor %}
<br>
<p><div class="text-center"><a style="border: 1px solid gray;" class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'create' %}">Write Message</a></div></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The basic idea is that I want to combine the "messages_form.html" and "messages_list.html" into one template file called "message.html".

***Can anyone help me?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something similar and here was my approach

**views.py**

```
from django.views import View

class MessageView(View):
    template_name = 'message.html'
    queryset = Messages.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MessageForm()
        context = {
            'object_list': self.get_queryset(),
            "form": form
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = MessageForm()
            return redirect('/message')

        context = {
            'object_list': self.get_queryset(),
            "form": form
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

**message.html**

```
{% extends "message/base.html" %}

{% block head_block %}
<title>Message</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

{% for message in object_list %}
<h3><div class="text-center"><span class="label label-default">{{ message.message }}</span></div></h3>
{% endfor %}

<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="text-center" style="position: fixed; top: 500px;">
    <span style="margin: 10px;">{{ form }}</span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-group btn-group-lg" >
  </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Display your view in a url

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import MessageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('message', MessageView.as_view(), name='messages'),
]
```

Comment: Everything works as far as I can tell, except when I click "send". It will save the object into the database, but it won't update the webpage with the info

Comment: It will update the page if I restart the server, but that's it.

Comment: Add a return redirect after saving the form on the post function so that the page is reloaded after saving the form. I have edited to include the line.